# Laptop heats up during gaming when Maximum CPU State is set to 100%

Tags: laptop, cpu, cooling

I have i7 2.2 GHZ 2nd gen processor with turbo boost up to 3 GHZ 8gb ram and amd graphic card.
On my laptop I used balanced power plan in this plan by default the "Maximum CPU State" is 100%
When I play games like Witcher 3 and Dota 2 the laptop heats up to 75 degrees in amount 10 minutes I can feel a bit of heat on the left side of the keyboard, i can also hear the fan nose which is inevitable at 75 degrees.
The average temperature while not gaming and doing other tasks is 56 to 59 degrees at 26 degrees celsius room temperature.

BUT;
When I reduce the "Maximum CPU State" to 50% in the power options and play games like dota 2 and witcher 3 the temperature always remains under 68 degrees and I can hardly hear any fan noise the laptop doesn't heat up.
 I dont know if it drops fps i didnt notice it nor measured it.

So what is likely to cause this do I have to change the thermal paste ?

Answer (score 1):

75°C is not that high of a temperature for a laptop CPU. Laptops tend to run at higher temperatures than desktops since they have way less space for heat pipes, fans, etc... replacing thermal compound on your CPU or GPU may decrease your temps slightly, but don't expect anything crazy, the most I've seen so far is maybe 3°C, unless of course the paste that's in there now is completely dry, but that would be weird for a 5-6 year old laptop.

Also, what were the temps let's say a year ago?

Answer (score 0):

OK First of all, Laptops do heat more or less depending on the conditions.

There are generally two reason of over heating :

1. Dust in the Fan(s) or in their vent. Make sure all the fans are clean.
2. Inefficient heat transfer due to old or lack of thermal paste between the CPU and heat sink.

Comment: In fact I installed a new fan few weeks ago and cleaned the dust

Answer (score 0):

Did your computer already had this problem before you changed the fan?

Anyway for a laptop it's pretty normal to become kind of noisy under heavy charge, they are more or less all like that.

You could try to elevate your laptop to improve the air flow under it (just put him on 2 object at the back, 2 small block of any kind).

Of course playing with the computer on your leg, a blanket, a sofa, or any soft surface is usually a bad idea as it block the airflow.

Last resort would be to use external fan if your internal one is not the cause of the problem.
There is plenty on Amazon/Ebay/Aliexpress/... just search for "Laptop fan".

Comment: I changed the fan because the old fan was nearly 3 years old and making grinding noise and the new fan works perfectly and there is some improvement after changing the fan. It was overheating even more before the fan replacement. I dont keep the laptop on a flat solid surface.